# Adding constraint in Opta Planner

Tags: java, maven, drools, optaplanner

I am trying to add a constraint in this (https://github.com/kiegroup/optaweb-employee-rostering) application. I am a beginner at this, so please if anyone knows how to add the following constraint in this class, it would be great:

">5 12hr consecutive shifts is not allowed"

If I know how to add one, I can add more. Here is the code that I was trying to write for this rule in Drools. It is not the most optimized, I just need to make it work.

```
rule "More than 5 12hr consecutive shifts is not allowed"
when

    $s : Shift(
                    employee != null,
                    $e : employee,
                    $firstEndDateTime : endDateTime,
                    $firstEndDateTime.until(startDateTime, ChronoUnit.HOURS) >=12)

    $s2 : Shift(
                    employee == $e,
                    $firstEndDateTime == startDateTime,
                    this != $s,
                    $secondEndDateTime : endDateTime,
                    $secondEndDateTime > startDateTime,
                    $secondEndDateTime.until(startDateTime, ChronoUnit.HOURS) >=12)
    $s3 : Shift(
                    employee == $e,
                    $secondEndDateTime == startDateTime,
                    this != $s,
                    this != $s2,
                    $thirdEndDateTime : endDateTime,
                    $thirdEndDateTime > startDateTime,
                    $thirdEndDateTime.until(startDateTime, ChronoUnit.HOURS) >=12)
    $s4 : Shift(
                    employee == $e,
                    $thirdEndDateTime== startDateTime,
                    this != $s,
                    this != $s2,
                    this != $s3,
                    $forthEndDateTime : endDateTime,
                    $forthEndDateTime > startDateTime,
                    $forthEndDateTime.until(startDateTime, ChronoUnit.HOURS) >=12)
    $s5 : Shift(
                    employee == $e,
                    $forthEndDateTime ==startDateTime,
                    this != $s,
                    this != $s2,
                    this != $s3,
                    this != $s4,
                    $fifthEndDateTime : endDateTime,
                    $fifthEndDateTime > startDateTime,
                    $fifthEndDateTime.until(startDateTime, ChronoUnit.HOURS) >=12)
    $s6 : Shift(
                    employee == $e,
                    $fifthEndDateTime ==startDateTime,
                    this != $s,
                    this != $s2,
                    this != $s3,
                    this != $s4,
                    this != $s5)
then
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -10);
```

end

Here is the class where I am adding rule. https://github.com/kiegroup/optaweb-employee-rostering/blob/master/optaweb-employee-rostering-backend/src/main/resources/org/optaweb/employeerostering/service/solver/employeeRosteringScoreRules.drl

The problem is in this class. When I try to write a method for the rule that I am adding. I am not sure how would I write it.

```
public final class EmployeeRosteringConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider {

private static final String CONSTRAINT_NO_MORE_THAN_12_HOUR_CONSECUTIVE_SHIFTS_ALLOWED =
        ">=6 12hr consecutive shifts is not allowed";

private static BiConstraintStream<EmployeeAvailability, Shift> getConstraintStreamWithAvailabilityIntersections(
        ConstraintFactory constraintFactory, EmployeeAvailabilityState employeeAvailabilityState) {
    return constraintFactory.from(EmployeeAvailability.class)
            .filter(employeeAvailability -> employeeAvailability.getState() == employeeAvailabilityState)
            .join(Shift.class,
                    equal(EmployeeAvailability::getEmployee, Shift::getEmployee),
                    lessThan(EmployeeAvailability::getStartDateTime, Shift::getEndDateTime),
                    greaterThan(EmployeeAvailability::getEndDateTime, Shift::getStartDateTime));
}

private static UniConstraintStream<Shift> getAssignedShiftConstraintStream(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.fromUnfiltered(Shift.class) // To match DRL
            .filter(shift -> shift.getEmployee() != null);
}

private static LocalDate extractFirstDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek weekStarting, OffsetDateTime date) {
    return date.with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(weekStarting)).toLocalDate();
}

@Override
public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return new Constraint[]{
            requiredSkillForShift(constraintFactory),
            unavailableEmployeeTimeSlot(constraintFactory),
            noOverlappingShifts(constraintFactory),
            noMoreThanTwoConsecutiveShifts(constraintFactory),
            breakBetweenNonConsecutiveShiftsIsAtLeastTenHours(constraintFactory),
            dailyMinutesMustNotExceedContractMaximum(constraintFactory),
            weeklyMinutesMustNotExceedContractMaximum(constraintFactory),
            monthlyMinutesMustNotExceedContractMaximum(constraintFactory),
            yearlyMinutesMustNotExceedContractMaximum(constraintFactory),
            assignEveryShift(constraintFactory),
            employeeIsNotOriginalEmployee(constraintFactory),
            undesiredEmployeeTimeSlot(constraintFactory),
            desiredEmployeeTimeSlot(constraintFactory),
            employeeNotRotationEmployee(constraintFactory),
            moreThanFive12HourConsecutiveShiftsNotAllowed(constraintFactory)
    };
}



Constraint requiredSkillForShift(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return getAssignedShiftConstraintStream(constraintFactory)
            .filter(shift -> !shift.hasRequiredSkills())
            .penalizeConfigurableLong(CONSTRAINT_REQUIRED_SKILL_FOR_A_SHIFT, Shift::getLengthInMinutes);
}

Constraint unavailableEmployeeTimeSlot(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return getConstraintStreamWithAvailabilityIntersections(constraintFactory, UNAVAILABLE)
            .penalizeConfigurableLong(CONSTRAINT_UNAVAILABLE_TIME_SLOT_FOR_AN_EMPLOYEE,
                    ((employeeAvailability, shift) -> shift.getLengthInMinutes()));
}

Constraint noOverlappingShifts(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return getAssignedShiftConstraintStream(constraintFactory)
            .join(Shift.class,
                    equal(Shift::getEmployee),
                    lessThan(Shift::getStartDateTime, Shift::getEndDateTime),
                    greaterThan(Shift::getEndDateTime, Shift::getStartDateTime))
            .filter((shift, otherShift) -> !Objects.equals(shift, otherShift))
            .penalizeConfigurableLong(CONSTRAINT_NO_OVERLAPPING_SHIFTS,
                    (shift, otherShift) -> otherShift.getLengthInMinutes());
}

Constraint noMoreThanTwoConsecutiveShifts(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return getAssignedShiftConstraintStream(constraintFactory)
            .join(Shift.class,
                    equal(Shift::getEmployee),
                    equal(Shift::getEndDateTime, Shift::getStartDateTime))
            .filter((s1, s2) -> !Objects.equals(s1, s2))
            .join(Shift.class,
                    equal((s1, s2) -> s2.getEmployee(), Shift::getEmployee),
                    equal((s1, s2) -> s2.getEndDateTime(), Shift::getStartDateTime))
            .penalizeConfigurableLong(CONSTRAINT_NO_MORE_THAN_2_CONSECUTIVE_SHIFTS,
                    (s1, s2, s3) -> s3.getLengthInMinutes());
}

Constraint moreThanFive12HourConsecutiveShiftsNotAllowed(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return getAssignedShiftConstraintStream(constraintFactory)
            .join(Shift.class,
                    equal(Shift::getEmployee),
                    equal(Shift::getEndDateTime, Shift::getStartDateTime))
            .filter((s1, s2) -> !Objects.equals(s1, s2))
            .filter((s1, s2) -> s1.getEndDateTime().until(s2.getStartDateTime(), ChronoUnit.HOURS) >= 12)
            .join(Shift.class,
                    equal((s1, s2) -> s2.getEmployee(), Shift::getEmployee),
                    equal((s1, s2) -> s2.getEndDateTime(), Shift::getStartDateTime))


            .penalizeConfigurableLong(CONSTRAINT_NO_MORE_THAN_12_HOUR_CONSECUTIVE_SHIFTS_ALLOWED,
                    (s1, s2, s3) -> s3.getLengthInMinutes());
}

Constraint breakBetweenNonConsecutiveShiftsIsAtLeastTenHours(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return getAssignedShiftConstraintStream(constraintFactory)
            .join(Shift.class,
                    equal(Shift::getEmployee),
                    lessThan(Shift::getEndDateTime, Shift::getStartDateTime))
            .filter((s1, s2) -> !Objects.equals(s1, s2))
            .filter((s1, s2) -> s1.getEndDateTime().until(s2.getStartDateTime(), ChronoUnit.HOURS) <16)
            .penalizeConfigurableLong(CONSTRAINT_BREAK_BETWEEN_NON_CONSECUTIVE_SHIFTS, (s1, s2) -> {
                long breakLength = s1.getEndDateTime().until(s2.getStartDateTime(), ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
                return (16 * 60) - breakLength;
            });
}

Constraint dailyMinutesMustNotExceedContractMaximum(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.from(Employee.class)
            .filter(employee -> employee.getContract().getMaximumMinutesPerDay() != null)
            .join(Shift.class, equal(Function.identity(), Shift::getEmployee))
            .groupBy((employee, shift) -> employee,
                    (employee, shift) -> shift.getStartDateTime().toLocalDate(),
                    sumDuration((employee, shift) ->
                            between(shift.getStartDateTime(), shift.getEndDateTime())))
            .filter((employee, firstDayOfWeek, totalWorkingTime) ->
                    totalWorkingTime.toMinutes() > employee.getContract().getMaximumMinutesPerDay())
            .penalizeConfigurableLong(CONSTRAINT_DAILY_MINUTES_MUST_NOT_EXCEED_CONTRACT_MAXIMUM,
                    (employee, firstDayOfWeek, totalWorkingTime) ->
                            totalWorkingTime.toMinutes() - employee.getContract().getMaximumMinutesPerDay());
}

Constraint weeklyMinutesMustNotExceedContractMaximum(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.from(RosterConstraintConfiguration.class)
            .join(Employee.class)
            .filter((configuration, employee) -> employee.getContract().getMaximumMinutesPerWeek() != null)
            .join(Shift.class, equal((configuration, employee) -> employee, Shift::getEmployee))
            .groupBy((configuration, employee, shift) -> employee,
                    (configuration, employee, shift) ->
                            extractFirstDayOfWeek(configuration.getWeekStartDay(), shift.getStartDateTime()),
                    sumDuration((configuration, employee, shift) ->
                            between(shift.getStartDateTime(), shift.getEndDateTime())))
            .filter((employee, firstDayOfWeek, totalWorkingTime) ->
                    totalWorkingTime.toMinutes() > employee.getContract().getMaximumMinutesPerWeek())
            .penalizeConfigurableLong(CONSTRAINT_WEEKLY_MINUTES_MUST_NOT_EXCEED_CONTRACT_MAXIMUM,
                    (employee, firstDayOfWeek, totalWorkingTime) ->
                            totalWorkingTime.toMinutes() - employee.getContract().getMaximumMinutesPerWeek());
}

Constraint monthlyMinutesMustNotExceedContractMaximum(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.from(Employee.class)
            .filter(employee -> employee.getContract().getMaximumMinutesPerMonth() != null)
            .join(Shift.class, equal(Functions.identity(), Shift::getEmployee))
            .groupBy((employee, shift) -> employee,
                    (employee, shift) -> YearMonth.from(shift.getStartDateTime()),
                    sumDuration((employee, shift) ->
                            between(shift.getStartDateTime(), shift.getEndDateTime())))
            .filter((employee, firstDayOfWeek, totalWorkingTime) ->
                    totalWorkingTime.toMinutes() > employee.getContract().getMaximumMinutesPerMonth())
            .penalizeConfigurableLong(CONSTRAINT_MONTHLY_MINUTES_MUST_NOT_EXCEED_CONTRACT_MAXIMUM,
                    (employee, firstDayOfWeek, totalWorkingTime) ->
                            totalWorkingTime.toMinutes() - employee.getContract().getMaximumMinutesPerMonth());
}

Constraint yearlyMinutesMustNotExceedContractMaximum(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.from(Employee.class)
            .filter(employee -> employee.getContract().getMaximumMinutesPerYear() != null)
            .join(Shift.class, equal(Functions.identity(), Shift::getEmployee))
            .groupBy((employee, shift) -> employee,
                    (employee, shift) -> shift.getStartDateTime().getYear(),
                    sumDuration((employee, shift) -> between(shift.getStartDateTime(), shift.getEndDateTime())))
            .filter((employee, firstDayOfWeek, totalWorkingTime) ->
                    totalWorkingTime.toMinutes() > employee.getContract().getMaximumMinutesPerYear())
            .penalizeConfigurableLong(CONSTRAINT_YEARLY_MINUTES_MUST_NOT_EXCEED_CONTRACT_MAXIMUM,
                    (employee, firstDayOfWeek, totalWorkingTime) ->
                            totalWorkingTime.toMinutes() - employee.getContract().getMaximumMinutesPerYear());
}

Constraint assignEveryShift(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.fromUnfiltered(Shift.class) // To match DRL.
            .filter(shift -> shift.getEmployee() == null)
            .penalizeConfigurable(CONSTRAINT_ASSIGN_EVERY_SHIFT);
}

Constraint employeeIsNotOriginalEmployee(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return getAssignedShiftConstraintStream(constraintFactory)
            .filter(shift -> shift.getOriginalEmployee() != null)
            .filter(shift -> !Objects.equals(shift.getEmployee(), shift.getOriginalEmployee()))
            .penalizeConfigurableLong(CONSTRAINT_EMPLOYEE_IS_NOT_ORIGINAL_EMPLOYEE, Shift::getLengthInMinutes);
}

Constraint undesiredEmployeeTimeSlot(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return getConstraintStreamWithAvailabilityIntersections(constraintFactory, UNDESIRED)
            .penalizeConfigurableLong(CONSTRAINT_UNDESIRED_TIME_SLOT_FOR_AN_EMPLOYEE,
                    (employeeAvailability, shift) -> employeeAvailability.getDuration().toMinutes());
}

Constraint desiredEmployeeTimeSlot(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return getConstraintStreamWithAvailabilityIntersections(constraintFactory, DESIRED)
            .rewardConfigurableLong(CONSTRAINT_DESIRED_TIME_SLOT_FOR_AN_EMPLOYEE,
                    (employeeAvailability, shift) -> employeeAvailability.getDuration().toMinutes());
}

Constraint employeeNotRotationEmployee(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return getAssignedShiftConstraintStream(constraintFactory)
            .filter(shift -> !Objects.equals(shift.getRotationEmployee(), shift.getEmployee()))
            .penalizeConfigurableLong(CONSTRAINT_EMPLOYEE_IS_NOT_ROTATION_EMPLOYEE, Shift::getLengthInMinutes);
}
```

}

I am trying to write the following method for the new rule:

```
Constraint moreThanFive12HourConsecutiveShiftsNotAllowed(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return getAssignedShiftConstraintStream(constraintFactory)
            .join(Shift.class,
                    equal(Shift::getEmployee),
                    equal(Shift::getEndDateTime, Shift::getStartDateTime))
            .filter((s1, s2) -> !Objects.equals(s1, s2))
            .filter((s1, s2) -> s1.getEndDateTime().until(s2.getStartDateTime(), ChronoUnit.HOURS) >= 12)
            .join(Shift.class,
                    equal((s1, s2) -> s2.getEmployee(), Shift::getEmployee),
                    equal((s1, s2) -> s2.getEndDateTime(), Shift::getStartDateTime))


            .penalizeConfigurableLong(CONSTRAINT_NO_MORE_THAN_12_HOUR_CONSECUTIVE_SHIFTS_ALLOWED,
                    (s1, s2, s3) -> s3.getLengthInMinutes());
}
```

It is not correct, I need to add a few things to make sure of no >5 consecutive shifts.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Consecutive constraints with a dynamic *n* are an API gap of ConstraintStreams (it's on our todo list). In DRL they're a big pain, due to the insertLogicals. In your case you're hardcoding the n to 5, so both CS and DRL are possible.

Comment: I am hard coding it. I just need to make it work somehow. If I can do that, it would solve my issue. I'm not too worried about optimizing yet.